# Is 'yet to arrive' a direct object of 'have'?

Tags: to-infinitive, direct-objects

> They have yet to arrive.

In this sentence, the understood meaning is that 'they' are going to arrive, but they haven't arrived yet. However, I'm struggling to break this down grammatically.

In the alternative structure 'they have not yet arrived', this is clearly present-perfect tense with the adverb 'yet' to indicate that it hasn't happened at that point. However, 'have' is clearly not an auxiliary verb in the example above, so does that mean the to-infinitive phrase/clause is a direct object of the verb 'have'?

Comment: No: only noun phrases can be objects. "Have" is a catenative verb, and the subordinate infinitival clause "yet to arrive" is its catenative complement.

Comment: I'd say ***to have*** in the cited context is just an ***auxiliary verb***, and I don't think auxiliary verbs can have "objects". No-one would suggest ***arrived*** is the "object" of *They **have** arrived*, and I don't see why it should make any difference if we tweak the wording slightly to ***They have not yet arrived*** or ***They have yet to arrive***.

Comment: This is tricky because "have yet to VERB" is an idiom and may be fossilized. _?Have they yet to arrive?_ _\*They have already/still to arrive._ A similar expression is "have only to VERB".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't see how 'have' is an auxiliary verb in this instance. In my second example, 'have' forms the the present-perfect tense with the past participle 'arrived', but that's an entirely different construction.

Comment: Okay - as a competent native speaker I don't really need to know the exact definitions of  terms like "auxiliary verb". But prompted by your comment I had no trouble finding [***Have to** is NOT an auxiliary verb.*](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-modals-have-to-must-not.htm#:~:text=Have%20to%20is%20NOT%20an,have%20to%20here%20for%20convenience.) I'm not gonna bother checking for my other example *They **have** arrived* (which imho is *much* more likely to be called an auxiliary usage) - if my perspective helps you understand English, that's all well and good. If not, just ignore it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Apologies. That wasn't a critique. I thought it might prompt you to explain something I wasn't aware of. Just trying to learn :)

Comment: No, I accept you're probably quite correct in pointing out that I'm using "auxiliary verb" loosely / incorrectly (but I'm not convinced my link to that ***to have to = must*** page is even relevant, since it's *not* the same usage as *to **have yet to** [have done something]* anyway). But I'm not entirely clear what *difference* it would make to your ability to understand English if you knew for sure why "yet to arrive" wouldn't be categorised as an "object" by people who *do* know the exact relevant terminology (such as @BillJ above! :)

Comment: ...it might help you to note that *They **are** yet to arrive* used to be a perfectly valid alternative to *They **have** yet to arrive*. It's still "syntactically valid", but idiomatically, that particular use of "auxiliary" ***to be*** has fallen out of favour today.

Answer (score -1):

Objects answer the question *what?*.  They do not answer the question *to what?*.  @BillJ's comment is the answer.

Another way of looking at it to help understand: If you respond with an infinitive-as-complement where a noun-phrase-as-object is expected for certain verbs, it's usually OK, but it does rather fundamentally alter the root meaning of the conversation.

> A: What do you want?  The red cup or the blue cup? (Conversation is about which X B gets)

> B: I want to stop drinking. (Conversation is now shifted to what B wants to do)